# How do I bind to the Property type event in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a python tkinter program to investigate how I can make a responsive text. After reviewing certain tkinter articles. I decided that rowconfigure and columnconfigure is just not enough, since the font size of the text will also need to change. So I decided to bind to an event, such that whenever the windows size is changed, I can look at the windows size and decide the text font like is done in bootstrap js. My problem is that there is only one text I can find that explains how I can bind to a window resize event, but it is [written for Tk/Tcl](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm) and I do not understand how that translates to python.

I can see from that file that I will need to do something like

```
root.bind("<Property>", on_resize_do_something_function)
```

but how do I specify the property name (size) which I want to watch for. Various hints are around the end of the page, but I do not understand how to translate them to python. Precisely, how I can bind to a property change event on a tk window in python? I posted a link to the page above in case it went unnoticed.

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to capture changes to the `root` window, such as the user resizing or moving the window, you can bind to the `'<Configure>'` event, e.g.:

```
def on_resize(e):
    global last_size  # allow this function to update the 'last_size' value
    # check if this event was generated by the root window
    # and if the size of the window has changed from the last event
    if str(e.widget) == '.' and (e.width, e.height) != last_size:
        ...  # do something!
        last_size = (e.width, e.height)  # update with the new root window size


root.bind('<Configure>', on_resize)
# get the initial size of the root window
last_size = (root.winfo_width, root.winfo_height)
```

Note that this event will fire immediately when the `root` window is created, but that's not likely to cause issues in most cases

The `Configure` `event` object passed has the following properties:

- `event.x` - the x position of the root window
- `event.y` - the y position of the root window
- `event.width` - the width of the root window
- `event.height` - the height of the root window

Comment: It's important to mention that if you bind to the root window, the binding will trigger for every single widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley Good to know! Would it make sense then to trap `event.widget` in the callback and throw away anything that's not relevant? I.e., any widget other than `.`?

Comment: yes. If you bind to the root menu and only want to take action on the root window, it would be good to add a conditional check for that.

Comment: @BryanOakley Easy enough - I'll make the edit. Thanks for the info!

Comment: from the page, the Configure event will also be triggered if the border width or position changes, Do you know how I can do this just for size changes?

Comment: @Alphonsus A simple solution is to keep track of the size of the `root` window globally and then discard any events where the `event.width` or `event.height` haven't changed, then update that global value to the new size as needed. I'll update my answer to include this.